# fragment - getView() method return NULL

Tags: android, android-fragments, getview

I don't know why in my fragment when i call getView it return NULL.
I Know that i can **call getView** just **after** the execution of the **onCreateView method**
I debugged my app: and i checked that first is called the onCreateView method.
So i don't know where is the problem.

I show to you my code:
this is my main activity and when a user click in the drawer menu i check which voice of the menu is pressed:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
     ...    
     if (position == 7) {
                CreaVotoFragment fragment = CreaVotoFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                        .commit();
                //Mostra un Dialog che consente l'eliminazione di un corso
                fragment.createMark(this);
     }
     ...
 }
```

In this case the user pressed the voice menu number 7, so inside this block I create a new 
Fragment, with the static method newIstance.
 this is the method:

```
public static CreaVotoFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    CreaVotoFragment fragment = new CreaVotoFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

after that i simply give the fragment to the method: replace.
it work and i can also see that he call onCreateView method overrided in the class CreaVotoFragment.
The problem begin when i call with the createMark method (last line of the if block).
 inside of the createMark method, when i call getView, return to me a null pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should notice that `commit()` will run on `Handler.post()`. That means that your fragment's view will be created AFTER `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected`.

Better if you call view-related-methods from inside fragment to constrain view's lifecycle.

Comment: so i could call the createMark() method inside the onCreateView fragment method right?

Comment: Yes. But notice than getView() will return view only after onCreateView(). If you want to call getView() in some methods then just do it between onCreateView() and onDestroyView()